# How to make a Menu invisible in CSS?

Tags: css, menu

I designed a template-based web page: [Website](http://www.avalue.com.mx)

There's a Menu "Avalúos Inmobiliarios" I don't want to show up. The solution I think of is to either change the menu background color to #173336 (like the background), take this menu off or make it 100% transparent.

The only thing my template service provider allows me in the code is to include CSS.

This is the solution I thought with my limited knowledge was (not working):

```
li a:visited {
    background-color: #173336;
}
```

So do you suggest any solution with a simple code that could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
.navbar .navbar-inner .container .nav li {
    display: none;
}
```